# How to read class attribute on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-phone-8.1, custom-attributes

How can I read attribute of a class in Windows Phone?

```
public static void DoSth<T>(T sth)
    where T : SomeClass
{
    MyAttribute a = // Get "MyAttribute" from sth
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection works somewhat differently in .NET for Windows Store apps. You probably have to access this through `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` like so:

```
MyAttribute a = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>()
```

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx) explains some of the differences in the Reflection APIs and why they exist.

In short, the authors wanted to expand the scenarios for Reflection and the design they settled on has a sort of "light-weight" Type class and a "heavy-weight" TypeInfo class. However for backwards compatibility in the full framework Type can still be used in the old heavy-weight way. On .NET for Windows Store, they had the chance make a single consistent API so they did that. Therefore Reflection code that works on .NET for Windows Store works in the full .NET framework but not the other way around.